# Add to arraylist everytime time activity starts or add account

Tags: android, arraylist

I am developing an app where I can Add Accounts, View Accounts and View Balances and View Transactions.

It is like a bankaccount for kids.

I want to be able to add the account name, account starting balance.

After that I want the names of the account in a listview when I click on View Accounts and the when I click on the list items I want to do some transactions (deposit and withdraw).

Also on ViewBalances, I want the same list view to pop up and I want to see the balances.

Each transaction, with a description, balance and date must be stored in a different array.

How can I save everything to arraylists and make it visible in the other activities?

Please help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to have a central location where your arraylist is available to every Activity.
So you can have a central Object with static access methods to get the ArrayList and any other info you want to store. If you want to store it persistently you should use a Database or similar.
For that have a look at
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can make you custom object class and make that parcelable. see [here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/03/example-to-implement-parcelable.html)